# How to Enable Azure Diagnostics in Cloud Services

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

I want to enable azure diagnostics for my azure cloud service but I'm a little bit confused.

I read the article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics. I found also that I can enable azure diagnostics in the cloud service properties page by checking "Enable Diagnostics" in the Configuration tab of the cloud service. Also I can go more advanced by clicking the Configure button that shows up when you enable diagnostics.

The cause of my confusion is why in the article says you need to download the WadConfig.xsd file and configure everything and then upload an xml file while you can do the same thing (not sure the same thing) in the cloud service properties configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Azure SDK 2.5 and later allow us to enable diagnostics and configure diagnostics configuration in UI by right-clicking on the Role and selecting Properties. But developers using Azure SDK 2.4 and previous versions can not manage diagnostic configuration in Visual Studio .

For detailed information, please read [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2014/12/02/windows-azure-diagnostics-upgrading-from-azure-sdk-2-4-to-azure-sdk-2-5/).

Comment: Thanx, very helpful